# How to stop rendering image url present in html content using aspose

Tags: java, aspose.words, aspose.pdf, aspose-slides

I am using below code to convert docx/doc/txt files to image
using aspose-words-15.8.0-jdk16.jar

```
com.aspose.words.Document doc = new com.aspose.words.Document(new ByteArrayInputStream(origData));
ImageSaveOptions saveOptions = new ImageSaveOptions(SaveFormat.JPEG);
saveOptions.setPageCount(1);
saveOptions.setPageIndex(0);
doc.save(outputImage, saveOptions);
```

if txt file is containing html content with image src tag its trying to render image. this is security issue. i dont want to render image. what changes i need to make from our side ?

Comment: As a fallback, you could strip the images or src tags from the docx/doc/txt file before loading and converting it with aspose words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly specify load format as TXT, in this case HTML tags in your TXT document will not be interpreted:

```java
LoadOptions opt = new LoadOptions();
opt.setLoadFormat(LoadFormat.TEXT);
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\in.txt", opt);
```

Also, you can skip loading external resources upon loading document using [IResourceLoadingCallback](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/iresourceloadingcallback/).

```java
LoadOptions opt = new LoadOptions();
opt.setResourceLoadingCallback(new SkipImgCallback());
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\in.html", opt);
```

```java
static final class SkipImgCallback implements IResourceLoadingCallback {
    @Override
    public int resourceLoading(final ResourceLoadingArgs args) throws Exception {
        return ResourceLoadingAction.SKIP;
    }
}
```